# React/Redux Variable returning HTML in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently working on a React webapp, and when I build and serve the application, a variable that I use to store a schedule is instead being filled with the page's HTML?

The app works perfectly in development, but has issues in production.

The variable is fetched using a Redux action where it queries my database.

---

#### Component:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import Game from './Game';

//Redux
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getSchedule } from '../actions/schedule';

const Schedule = ({ scheduleObj:{schedule, loading}, getSchedule }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getSchedule('all');
  }, [loading]);

  const [type, setType] = useState(0);

  const onChange = e => {
    getSchedule(e.target.value);
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Schedule Loading</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <p>Schedule</p>

        <select id='schedule' onChange={e => onChange(e)}>
          <option value='all'>All Sports</option>
          <option value='fav'>Favourite Sports</option>
          <option value='mbasketball'>Axemen Basketball</option>
          <option value='mfootball'>Axemen Football</option>
          <option value='mhockey'>Axemen Hockey</option>
          <option value='msoccer'>Axemen Soccer</option>
          <option value='mswimming'>Axemen Swimming</option>
          <option value='wbasketball'>Axewomen Basketball</option>
          <option value='wcrosscountry'>Axewomen Cross Country</option>
          <option value='wrugby'>Axewomen Rugby</option>
          <option value='wsoccer'>Axewomen Soccer</option>
          <option value='wswimming'>Axewomen Swimming</option>
          <option value='wvolleyball'>Axewomen Volleyball</option>
        </select>
        {schedule}

      </Fragment>
      /*
      (schedule.length <1000) ? (schedule.map(game => (
          <Game key={game._id} gameID={game._id}/>
        ))) : 'Empty Schedule'
      */
    );
  }
};
Schedule.propTypes = {
  getSchedule: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  scheduleObj: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  scheduleObj: state.schedule,
  loading: state.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getSchedule })(Schedule);
```

---

The variable that is getting filled with the HTML is the schedule variable.

#### Example (Just drawing the contents of schedule as text):

[image: Error]

---

#### Here's what the page should look like

[image]

---

The schedule variable should contain a JSON array of objects.
Here is what it looks like console.log() 'd to in development.[image: JSON example]

---

Network Tab with Response (Production):
[image: Network Tab]

---

[image: Response]

Comment: Hey Sean, could you let know from where this variable called `schedule` is coming. It is just after the select tag gets closed in the code. `</select>
        {schedule}` Could this be the issue?

Comment: Yeah, in the error version shown I'm writing the contents to screen using that way to show what is inside it. However, in development and what we want it to be in production is with the commented code beneath it (`(schedule.length <1000) ? (schedule.map(game => (
          <Game key={game._id} gameID={game._id}/>
        ))) : 'Empty Schedule'`). I'm adding what it looks like in development now.

Comment: ok, but I do not see any schedule prop for that component. Did you mean to use `scheduleObj` instead?

Comment: scheduleObj contains schedule and loading, and we destructure it in the parameters of the functional component

Comment: oh ok, got it, sorry I missed it. Can you  console log to check what really comes in schedule from props though. Because, when you are mapping state to props, you have already mapped to only `schedule` from the state to the `scheduledObj` prop, and you have created a separate `loading` prop from it. Re-verify your props and state mapping to be sure.
`const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  scheduleObj: state.schedule,
  loading: state.loading
});`

Comment: No problem! Did you want to open a discussion? We're filling the comments right up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209217/discussion-between-anuradha-kumari-and-sean-moody).

Comment: onChange is triggering `getSchedule ` which I am assuming is an ajax call. Can you check network tab and see if that request is going in prod mode, and what the response content is.

Comment: getSchedule is a Redux action. Request is hitting the API route and returning HTML, attaching image of network tab. https://imgur.com/a/TV3qg9f - https://imgur.com/a/jrdhqw8

Comment: in that request you can see that you are not passing schedule value. redux has nothing to do here. the api should return json and not html.

Comment: The server is identical to the one as running in development mode, why would it suddenly be returning HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Found what the issue likely is. We run our backend requests via a proxy as defined in the package.json file, however this isn't a feature used in production environments.

Will update with the fix when found.

**Update:**
This was the issue. Deploying the app to Heroku works fine!

Comment: Hey Sean! I have the exact same problem. Redux is returning HTML elements rather than the JSON objects. What did you particularly change so that it works in production?